# How update Stored Procedure has Optional Parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

How can I alter Update Stored Procedure so if developer want to set only `Size` then he/she does not requireed to pass `TimeStamp`. Moreover, then what will be execute code for this procedure?

**Scenario:**

Update `TimeStamp = getdate()` field whose `SizeID = 1` AND `Size =Large`

Note: This field Parameters and condition parameters must be dynamic and optionals like in where `TimeStamp` can also be supplied.

**Update Stored Procedure:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Sizes_Update]

@SizeID    int,
@Size    varchar(50),
@TimeStamp    datetime

AS

Update Sizes

Set
    Size = @Size,
    TimeStamp = @TimeStamp
Where

SizeID = @SizeID
```

Answer (score 4):

one way

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Sizes_Update]
  @SizeID    int,
  @Size    varchar(50) = 'Large',
  @TimeStamp    datetime = null
AS
  Update Sizes
  Set
   Size = @Size,
   TimeStamp = coalesce(@TimeStamp,getdate())
  Where
   SizeID = @SizeID
```

Answer (score 3):

Just set the parameter to a default value, like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Sizes_Update]
  @SizeID    int,
  @Size    varchar(50),
  @TimeStamp    datetime = null
AS
  Update Sizes
  Set
   Size = @Size,
   TimeStamp = @TimeStamp
  Where
   SizeID = @SizeID
```

however, if you want the default value to be a result of a function call, you could use some special value that will be replaced by the function hole, like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Sizes_Update]
  @SizeID    int,
  @Size    varchar(50),
  @TimeStamp    datetime = null
AS
  if @TimeStamp is null
   set @TimeStamp = getdate()

   Update Sizes
   Set
     Size = @Size,
     TimeStamp = @TimeStamp
   Where SizeID = @SizeID
```

Comment: +1, although for something named @TimeStamp, I'd probably set the default value to getdate().

Comment: @SirDemon - you can't use GETDATE() as a default parameter value, has to be a constant

Comment: @Ada - I think SirDemon was talking about setting the default value of the column in the table as Getdate(), however, that won't work with update calls.

Comment: I pretty much meant what you've already added to your answer. I simply wouldn't have left a @timestamp to be null.